# Automorphism group homomorphism induced by the mapping between sets

Tags: group-theory

This is a question on Vakil's AG notes on category theory. Let A, B be two isomorphic objects in some category. So I can show that the isomorphism $F:A\to B$ induces a homomorphism by sending the $g\in Aut(A)$ to $g'\in Aut(B)$ by $F(gF^{-1}F(a))=g'(F(a))$. This can be checked as homormophism. I can further check this does induce an isomorphism between Aut(A) and Aut(B). However, I am not sure whether the condition of isomorphism between two objects A and B can be relaxed and still obtain an induced homomorphism?

Answer (score 1):

If $K:B \to A$ is another morphism, you get a function $\Phi:Aut(A) \to Aut(B)$ in the following way. $g\in Aut(A)$ maps to $\Phi(g)\in Aut(B)$ with $\Phi(g)(b)=F(g(K(b))$.

If you want $\Phi$ to be a homomorphism, you need, for every $g,g'\in Aut(A)$, $$F(gg'(K(b)))=\Phi(gg')(b)=\Phi(g)\Phi(g')(b)=F(g(KFg'(K(b)))).$$

One way to get this equality is to have $KF=Id_A$, which is weaker than asking that $K=F^{-1}$.

So the condition that $F$ is an isomorphism can be relaxed to the condition that $F$ admits a retract $K$, i.e., $KF=Id_A$.